# Refreshing a pivot table created in Excel Vba (ADODB Connection)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I can successfully create a pivot table in excel vba 2010 with the following code where the data come from an MS access database,

`Dim con As New ADODB.Connection`

`Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset`

`con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\SQL.accdb"`

`rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1", con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly`

`Set piv = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal)`

`Set piv.Recordset = rs`

`piv.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Range("A1"), TableName:="P2"`

`con.Close`

`Set rs = Nothing`

`Set con = Nothing`

But i when i change the SQL code of the recordset then the pivot can't be refreshed. In fact the pivot table has to be deleted and created over. Is there a way i can create a pivot table this way and refresh the data without deleting the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer was not quite what i was look for as different users would query from the database and will be using parameters as well, which could cause problems when multiple users query at the same time. But i did found a way to around my problem.

The code i placed above in my question, I can use to initially create my pivot and pull all the data through. I then build a separate Sub that can refresh the pivot table that looks as follows,

`Dim con As New ADODB.Connection`

`Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset`

`con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\SQL.accdb"`

`rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1", con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly`

`With Sheets(1).PivotTables("P2").PivotCache`

```
    Set .Recordset = rs
    .Refresh
```

`End With`

`Set rs = Nothing`

`con.Close`

`Set con = Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

A quick-fix, depending on how you usually update the SQL code, is as follows.

- **In ACCESS** , create a query, using *SQL mode* as
  `SELECT * FROM Table1` and save it as `Query1`
- **In EXCEL**, modify your code to `SELECT * FROM Query1`

That way, Excel will treat `Query1` as a **Table** for all practical purposes and you may make `Query1` in Access as complicated as you'd like, Excel will still pull up all its contents, keeping your code reusable.